# Problems using SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I am using a SQL Server Compact database for a project I am working on and have been having a hard time trying to insert data to the database.

My insert statement and everything is working fine and data gets inserted too and I can even do searches for the inserted data (while in the application).

The problem I am having is when I quit and re-run the application, it seems that the data was not inserted into the database and the tables are empty too.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: You probably have a bug somewhere. I suggest that you provide a *minimal* working example that reproduces the issue. (Note the word *minimal* -- nobody wants to read through hundred lines of code -- and the word *working* -- people should be able to take your code, paste it into Visual Studio and reproduce the issue.)

Comment: @SynerCoder: No, in SQL CE everything is written at once. Usually this is a sign of the SDF file being overwritten with an empty file.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that the SDF file is overwritten with an empty version whenever you rebuild/run the application?

Comment: Thank you. This never came to my thought that the db file would be over written every time I build the app. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

As Thorsten pointed out, check the Build Action on your SDF file.